# Magento 2: How can i reindex set in Reset mode programmatically

Tags: magento2

I just need to reset all indexing  programmatically without use of command.
Is there any way to do this . 
Any idea please share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset the state of index by below code

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory)
{
    $this->indexerCollection = $indexerCollectionFactory;
}

public function resetIndexer()
{
    $indexers = $this->indexerCollection->create()->getItems();

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterface $indexer */
    foreach ($indexers as $indexer) {
        try {
            $indexer->getState()
                ->setStatus(\Magento\Framework\Indexer\StateInterface::STATUS_INVALID)
                ->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //catch exception
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: working fine, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late
Please see - PHP file to reindex reset and view status of indexer

https://github.com/estvivek/External_magento_2_reindex_reset

https://github.com/estvivek/External_magento_2_reindex_reset/tree/master/subfolder will enable reset for failed indexers only rest of the features are same.

disclaimer - It was created for one of our websites and code is in my Github account.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement of the [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/202670/40734) by MeenakshiSundaram R :

In Magento 2.3 you can now call `$indexer->invalidate();` that will do the work for you :

```
 /**
 * Set indexer invalid
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function invalidate()
{
    $state = $this->getState();
    $state->setStatus(StateInterface::STATUS_INVALID);
    $state->save();
}
```